# Some problems while importing dart projects from windows to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dart

I was developing a dart project in windows, and for some reasons, I chosen to switch to Linux Ubuntu, but when I imported my projects, I got some problems like importing files ex:

```
import "../ds/userdata.dart";
```

I know there is a way to write this in Linux, secondly when i try to run an httpserver instance it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 1020
```

so any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

okey guys! after some work i found this: if you're working on a Dart project **don't ever use capital letters**, that's my problem of the imports, i named a folder: *DS* and a file *UserData.dart*, for the second one about the httpserver, try always to use a port **above 1024**, and that's a common http problem in Linux because ports under 1024 are all reserved!
i hope you can avoid this problems if you're trying to import any kind of projects from windows to ubuntu! thank you!

Comment: There was a discussion recently to change the style guide to use camel case for file names instead of all lower case, but it was dropped because the OSes handle them so differently.

Comment: I can also add advice. If you install Dart SDK on Windows does not install it in the path with spaces in names. Eg. "Program Files/dart".